# Converting JavaScript Object to JSON String Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am using the following code to convert js object to json but not seems to be working:

```
 var params = new Object(); 
      params.fileCode = $(this).val(); 

      var something = jQuery.stringify(params);
```

UPDATE 1:

I updated the code to this but still no success:

```
 var params = new Object(); 
      params.fileCode = $(this).val(); 

      var p = $.toJSON(params); // object does not support this property or method 

      var s = JSON.stringify(params); // JSON is not defined
```

Comment: What does `this` evaluate to?  Is it an element on the dom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery does not support the `stringify` method. Use `JSON.stringify` instead.

For backwards compability, you can include the `json2.js` file from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js.

Comment: Is there no built in function in jQuery library. I even used jQuery-json lib and $.toJSON(object) and it did not work either.

Comment: @azamsharp jQuery does not have a built-in support. Parsing a JSON string can be easily done with `eval` (ugly backward compability method), while `JSON.stringify` requires more code (see link in my answer).

Comment: Hi Rob, If I have js object how can I get JSON string. Do I have to download JSON.h. link please

Comment: Add the following code to your HTML document: `<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>`. This script is used to add `JSON` support to browsers which do not implement JSON natively. Then, if your JavaScript Object is called `obj`, the string can be obtained by using `var string = JSON.stringify(obj);`

Comment: I am using IE8 and it seems like on JSON.stringify(obj) is just dies. Any ideas?

Comment: I captured the error and it says JSON is undefined. I am referencing the json2.js from the CDN as Rob has posted above!

Comment: You have to include `json2.js` **before** using the JSON method. Otherwise, the could will fail.

Comment: json2 is added in the head section of the page!

Comment: Yes json2.js is added as the first js file on the page.

Comment: @azamsharp Can you provide the (relevant) code of your whole page **in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)**?